# How to change into indirect speech " She said to me, Where were you living before you came here?"

Tags: reported-speech

Do you think I am supposed to change the second part of the sentence as well which is " before I came here"?

Is this correct way to say, She asked me where I had been living before I came there.

Comment: Closer to the original: where I **was** living.

Comment: Your question title implies that *you* said *"She said to me, 'Where were you living before you came here?'"*, in which case you need to use ***single quotes*** (as I just did) to indicate that it's "reported speech ***within*** reported speech". If that's ***not*** what you've asking about, please edit your question title to move the first double-quote mark to immediately before the first word she said *(**Where**)*. Otherwise, please edit to include both types of quote marks as indicated.

Comment: ...I'm not sure why anyone would normally ask ***Where were you living before?*** like that. Plain "non-continuous" ***Where did you live before?*** is surely more natural.

Comment: It depends where 'here' is! If you are talking to someone in the town where you live, you can say 'before I came here'. If you are talking to someone in another place, or it's part of a story that might  be read by anyone, you have to use 'there' (since the reader probably isn't in your home town).

Comment: She asked me where I had been living before I came there. sounds okay ? or She asked me where I had been living before I had come there.

Comment: Yes, it sounds OK. There is no need to use the perfect tense.

Comment: It sounds like you're uncertain what your teacher or instructor wants you to do. We can't help with that. You'll have to ask. Your suggestion gets the tenses right, but choice of here/there, come/go, etc, is complex, and we can't tell if you're supposed to keep them or change them.

Comment: Do you think, in this particular indirect speech, clauses followed by "before", "after" "until" "when" etc remained unchanged? and Is there any way I could modify the sentence giving the same meaning as it was above? Before I came here, she asked me where I had been living. which one  makes more sense ? and why? thank you so much sir.

Answer (score 1):

You don’t backshift *I came* in the *before* clause:

> Direct: *She asked me, “Where were you living before you came to
> England?”*
>
> Indirect: *She asked me where I had been living before I came to
> England.* (not *had come*)

You can confirm that by comparing these:

> Direct: *She asked, “Where did you live when you were a child?”*
>
> Indirect: *She asked where I had lived when I was a child?”* (not *had
> been*)

If she said “here” — referring to e.g. England — you have three options, depending on context:

> The listener does not know where “here” is: *She asked me where I had
> been living before I came to England.*
>
> The listener knows that “here” is England and that you are not in
> England now: *She asked me where I had been living before I came
> there.*
>
> The listener knows that “here” is England and that you are in England
> now: *She asked me where I had been living before I came here.*

Answer (score 0):

In careful speech, you'd say *She asked me where I'd been living before I came there*, but many people would say *She asked me where I was living before I came there*, as we often do not bother with past perfect when the temporal relationships are clear without it.

You could say *She asked me where I'd been living before I'd come there*, but that sounds rather stilted and unnatural to me.

Comment: Do you think, in this particular indirect speech, clauses followed by "before", "after" "until" "when" etc remained unchanged? and Is there any way I could modify the sentence giving the same meaning as it was above? Before I came here, she asked me where I had been living. which one makes more sense ? and why? thank you so much sir.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. I suspect you're believing that English is like mathematics, and you can work out the equation and get the right answer, and a different expression gets a different answer; but language isn't like that. People say things that could be ambiguous or that when you analyse them seem to have a different meaning. I've given you my opinion (as a native speaker) of the possibilities.